# How to pass state from child to parent with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to build a website where the user can write a query in a searchbar and get some results back.

I created two components: `Searchform` (parent) and `Searchbar` (child).

I know how to update the state of the child:

```
function Searchbar() {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  return(
    <TextField
      defaultValue=""
      placeholder="Search"
      label="Search bar"
      fullWidth
      onChange={(event)=>setQuery(event.target.value)}
    />
  )
}
```

**However**, I am not sure how to send this new state to the parent.

```
function Searchform() {

  function handleSubmit() {
    console.log(query)
  }

  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  return(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="searchbar">
          <Searchbar />  # I think I have to do something here but not sure what.
        </div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
        Submit your search
      </Button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can only pass from parent to child but you can pass a callback from parent to child that the child can execute so the parent does something. Now both parent and child have to maintain a query, just pass query value and setQuery to child.

Comment: Thanks. Could you write it in code? It would be helpful for me to see how to do it for the first time. I am using Hooks, not sure if something changes,

Comment: Added answer with an optimized example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to maintain the query in the parent and pass value and onChange to child:

```
function Searchbar({ value, onChange }) {
  return (
    <TextField
      placeholder="Search"
      label="Search bar"
      fullWidth
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
}

function Searchform() {
  function handleSubmit() {
    console.log(query);
  }
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  //create onChange function that will never
  //  change during component life cycle
  const onChange = useCallback(
    e => setQuery(e.target.value),
    []
  );

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="searchbar">
        {/* pass value and onChange */}
        <Searchbar value={query} onChange={onChange} />
        but not sure what.
      </div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        type="submit"
      >
        Submit your search
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me what is the `[ ]` in the useCallback?

Comment: @Prova12 It is the [deps](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) argument, because it's empty the function will not be re created during the Component life cycle, this will cause React virtual dom compare to skip unnecessary renders.

Answer (score 0):

State should be hoisted to the top-most container that deals with the state, and then passed down through props (or providers for contexts).

To update the state, you must pass down a callback function (through props) from the parent to child components that allow the child to update the parent's state. The change will then propagate to all children during a re-render.

This is a universal React concept, whether using hooks or classes, [see the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

A basic example:

```js
const Parent = () => {

  const [query, setQuery] = useState(null);

  return <Child onQuery={setQuery} />;

}

const Child = ({ onQuery }) => (
  <TextField onChange={event => onQuery(event.target.value)} />
);
```

Comment: Since parent (SearchForm) maintains both value and onChange (query and setQuery) it would be better to make the text input a controlled input some buggy behavior can occur if you only do it half way.

Comment: True, that was not the goal of the example though

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
 function Searchform() {

  function handleSubmit() {
    console.log(query)
  }

  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  return(
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="searchbar">
          <Searchbar setQuery={setQuery} />
        </div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
        Submit your search
      </Button>
    </form>
  )
}



function Searchbar({setQuery}) {

 // const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  return(
    <TextField
      defaultValue=""
      placeholder="Search"
      label="Search bar"
      fullWidth
      onChange={(event)=>setQuery(event.target.value)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Since parent (SearchForm) maintains both value and onChange (query and setQuery) it would be better to make the text input a controlled input some buggy behavior can occur if you only do it half way.

Comment: absolutely !! my bad :|